# list of all commits SHA1_HASH

Tags: git

```
git init
echo 'I am foo' > foo.txt
git add foo.txt # this woould create a git commit object
echo ' I am foo2' > foo.txt
git add foo.txt # this would create another git commit object
git commit -m 'doe' # this would create two git 
                    # objects: one commit object and one tree object
```

How do I get a list of all 4 commits SHA1_HASH ?

```
cd .git/objects
ls
(master)$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   8 nsingh  staff  272 Mar 27 16:44 .
drwxr-xr-x  13 nsingh  staff  442 Mar 27 16:44 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 nsingh  staff  102 Mar 27 16:44 37
drwxr-xr-x   3 nsingh  staff  102 Mar 27 16:43 a2
drwxr-xr-x   3 nsingh  staff  102 Mar 27 16:44 e1
drwxr-xr-x   3 nsingh  staff  102 Mar 27 16:42 e6
drwxr-xr-x   2 nsingh  staff   68 Mar 27 16:42 info
drwxr-xr-x   2 nsingh  staff   68 Mar 27 16:42 pack
```

I can find the list of all 4 commits by looking at file here but there must be a better way.

Comment: You're also a bit mistaken about having created four commit objects. All `git add` does is check things into the index. You only created one commit, when you ran `git commit`. And you almost certainly have no need to know what the SHA1 of the tree for that commit is, but if you were dying to know, you could use `git log --pretty=%T` to see it.

Comment: The objects you've created by doing all this are: a commit (from git commit), a tree (the tree of that commit), and a blob (the contents of foo.txt). The first echo/add pair had no lasting affect, because you overwrote it with the next pair.

Comment: To learn more about the internals, try perhaps the git community book: http://book.git-scm.com/1_the_git_object_model.html or pro git: ttp://progit.org/book/ch9-2.html (among many many others)

Answer (score 4):

`git log --format=format:%H` will print out only the commit hashes, one per line. Take a look at the [pretty formats section](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) of `man git-log` for more info on the format options. The `--pretty=oneline` suggestion is similar, but will also give you the commit messages as well as the hashes.

Comment: In current versions of git, you don't need that extra prefix - you can just do `git log --pretty=%H`.

Answer (score 3):

Try `git log --pretty=oneline`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the abbreviated SHA 1, try `git log --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline`.